# is default handler mapping is overridden when we create custom handler mapping in spring mvc?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, model-view-controller

I want to know is default handler mapping created by spring mvc framework override if we create our custom handler mapping. I have doubt because i created custom handler mapping in two projects in one

1. BeanNameHandlerMapping
2. SimpleUrlHandlerMapping is injected in dispatcher servlet  but in another one these are not registered in dispatcher servlet

I am using different version of spring 3 framework for these two project. Is it because of version change in spring 3

I am not getting default handler mapping  in spring 3.0 but getting in spring 3 higher version

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Specify the [order](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/handler/AbstractHandlerMapping.html#setOrder-int-) of your custom `HandlerMapping` to have the lowest int value so that it gets tried first over the other registered HandlerMappings.

**Explanation**

Figuring out the available HandlerMappings in the web context is part of the `DispatcherServlet` initialisation:

[image]

That method, is discovering all the registered `HandlerMapping`s and as you can see it is sorting them *based on their defined order*.

[image]

Otherwise it is falling back on the default handlerMapping: the `BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping`

Comment: Yes initHandlerMapping(context) method  discovers the all handler mapping and registered them. My question was if I create a custom HandlerMapping (say MyCustomMapping) and specifying the lowest order so that it is tried first then all default mapping  BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping or other default mapping registered or not? @dismitrisli

Comment: @yoga: again looking at the above code you can find the answer. There is only one default HandlerMapping, the BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping and it's registered only when DispatcherServlet cannot find any explicitly registered HandlerMappings in the context (like your custom handler mapping). So if you define *any* handler mapping/mappings these will be the ones to get used according to the order, no defaults.

Comment: Yes I am also thinking this but in one of my project I define my custom mapping but default mapping  BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping is also get registered, I checked that by putting debug point on above method. but in another project it is not registered. only spring version is different as I mention in my fist qustion

Comment: @yoga: Even if that's the case, isn't your custom handler mapping getting picked up with lower order? If previous Spring version behaviour is different it should be visible in the code if it's registering default in any case.